# Adding a task to a playbook which must run even when other roles failed

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have the following playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: "{{ target }}"
  gather_facts: no

  roles:
   - role1
   - role2

  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: Role3
          ansible.builtin.include_role:
            name: role3
      rescue:
        - meta: clear_host_errors

    - ansible.builtin.include_role:
        name: final-role
```

I was expecting to achieve the following here:

- If role1 or role2 fails, there is no need to run final-role.
- If role 3 fails, I want to run final-role (mandatory).
- If role 3 fails, when finishing executing the playbook (this is, after running final-role), it should return FAILED status (as it would do if role3 failed and if it was not running inside the block).

The first 2 I achieved them already.
However what would be the best way to cause the play to FAIL after running-final role, if role3 failed before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not really get if you want to run `final_role` only if `role3` failed or always so here are the two options:

*Notes:*

- *although dash (`-`) is not strictly forbidden for role names, it will trigger errors in tools like `ansible-lint` and will be unconditionnaly transformed to `_` when uploading to galaxy. So I renamed `final-role` to `final_role` in the below examples as a good practice*
- *I'm not really sure why you use `clear_host_errors` in your playbook and left it untouched. But it is not mandatory/useful for the current issue*

**`final_role` only on failure**:

```yaml
    - block:
        - name: Run role3
          ansible.builtin.include_role:
            name: role3

      rescue:
        - meta: clear_host_errors

        - name: Run final role as we failed
          ansible.builtin.include_role:
            name: final_role
       
        - name: Report failure after rollback and remedy
          ansible.builtin.fail:
            msg: role3 failed
```

**`final_role` always and final failure if role3 failed**:

```yaml
    - block:
        - name: Run role3
          ansible.builtin.include_role:
            name: role3

      rescue:
        - meta: clear_host_errors

        - name: Register failure
          ansible.builtin.set_fact:
            role3_failed: true

      always:
        - name: Run final role
          ansible.builtin.include_role:
            name: final_role
       
        - name: Report failure if needed
          ansible.builtin.fail:
            msg: role3 failed
          when: role3_failed | d(false) | bool
```